# GET request with optional PathVariable returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I have the following controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{graphId}/from/{town1}/to/{town2}?maxStops={maxStops}",
                     "/{graphId}/from/{town1}/to/{town2}"})
public ResponseEntity<String> findRoutesWithMaxStops(
        @PathVariable Integer graphId,
        @PathVariable Character town1,
        @PathVariable Character town2,
        @PathVariable(required = false) Integer maxStops) {
    System.out.println(graphId);
    System.out.println(town1);
    System.out.println(town2);
    System.out.println(maxStops); //returns null

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("It worked out!");
}
```

I'm trying to pass the following URL on my GET request:

```
http://localhost:8080/routes/1/from/A/to/B?maxStops=1
```

But, for some reason, when I print the variable "maxStops", it is null. Why is that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use a `@PathVariable` instead of a `@RequestParam` for `maxStops`?

Comment: @Turing85 I honestly just couldn't tell the different between them. Could you help me, please? Would ```@RequestParam``` solve my problem? How would it look afterwards?

Comment: What Spring calls `@RequestParam` is generally known as [query parameter](https://branch.io/glossary/query-parameters) (in general, they are used to influence pagination, filtering and ordering). I am not sure whether this solves your problem (I do not have a reproducer at hand), but it might. I recommend reading a tutorial on Spring's `@RequestParam`, e.g. [this one from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param).

Comment: @Turing85 ```@RequestParam``` seemed to work for me. Thank you very much!